# How could alphanumeric be a character and not a string?

Tags: c, cs50, alphanumeric

In CS50 library there is function named `isalnum` that check whether a character is alphanumeric. However, that function only accepts a `char` not a `c-string` (*i.e.,* `char[]`).

By alphanumeric, I understand that is something as for example "7x", so it is two characters, one alphabetic and one numeric, so "7x" is a string not a char because it consist of the characters "7" and "x".

Now how could the function `isalnum` check if a single character is alphanumeric ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://manual.cs50.io/3/isalnum

Function `int isalnum(char c);`

> This function checks whether c is alphanumeric (i.e., a letter or a
> number) or not.

So it checks if is **either** a letter **or** a number not both simultaneously (*e.g.,* a1). Therefore, the parameter does not have to be a String, a char will be enough. With a `char` you can test **single** digits from `'0 to 9'` as well **single** letters, hence no need for Strings (or `char[]`).

The function will return `1` when the char `c` is either a letter form 'a to Z' or a digit from '0 to 9', `0` otherwise.